# Tiled maps look pixelated, but when moved, they look fine

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a tiled map in cocos2d-iphone. It uses .png images.

Sometimes, when you look closely enough, you will notice some parts "pixelated". Of bad quality. But then, if you move your character (and the map scrolls), suddenly it fixes and looks normal. If you keep on moving randomly, you might see it gets wrong again etc...

This never happened before until recently. But it is weird because I never touched the tiled maps ever again.

What could be causing this? iPhone 4, retina enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The sprite is probably positioned on a sub-pixel, such as `16.5f`, which could cause distortion.

Comment: I don't think I'm using subpixels... I went to configuration and have this:
#define CC_COCOSNODE_RENDER_SUBPIXEL 0
#define CC_SPRITEBATCHNODE_RENDER_SUBPIXEL 0